# Define custom view page template with theme_hook_suggestions

Tags: 7, views, theming

I would like to define 'theme_hook_suggestions' for a custom views-view.tpl.php file.

To achieve this, I wrote the following code into my template.php file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  // Some logic to decide if the hook_suggestions should set or not
  // ...
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'foo';
}
```

After that, I created a copy of views-view.tpl.php in the templates folder named foo.tpl.php.

Sadly, my template file is ignored by Drupal and the default views-view.tpl.php file is rendered on the page.

What's the matter? I debugged the theme_registry and the template path should be correct (points to my theme).

**Update**
The target is that I can switch between two template files which are defined in my preprocess function (see above). Because in some cases, my layout markup is significant different as in other cases.

I don't want to use the same template file for both cases; when I do this, the file is full of tousands of `if()` just for adjusting the markup for some cases.

Comment: Try to clear cache and check again.

Comment: Clear the cache didn't solve the problem

Comment: Why don't you use 'views-view.tpl.php' and customize it as per your requirement? Templates are generally used for customization.

Comment: I want to switch the template (a lot of layout markup inside the template) when several conditions are given and using the same template file for both cases is not very readful and hacky (my opinion)

Comment: My suggestion is to check all conditions in the preprocess function and just do the rendering in template (which is actually the preferred way)

Comment: I disagree with that @SureshR - taking a modular approach is much better than having a single template file with tons of `if`s in it, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is fine. The only problem is with the name of the hook suggestion and the equivelant tpl.php file.

Since you are preprocessing views_view the hook suggestion should be named something that starts with views_view ex: views_view__[anything]. Note that all the undersores will be replaced with dashes for the filename. So it should be something like views-view--[anything].tpl.php

For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  // Some logic to decide if the hook_suggestions should set or not
  // ...
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'views_view__foo';
}
```

And the filename will be views-view--foo.tpl.php

Comment: That clarifies an issue I was facing.. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple templates for views like :

views-view--home-slideshow-mobile.tpl.php
if your display is a block, you can write it like this :

views-view--home-slideshow-mobile--block.tpl.php
then you have templates for views fields :

views-view-fields--home-slideshow-mobile.tpl.php
Templates for views format (like unformatted for example) :

views-view-unformatted--home-slideshow-mobile.tpl.php
If you want to alter the template of your block, you can declare a block.tpl.php like :

block--my-block-module--my-block-machinename.tpl.php

You can copy the template and paste them in your theme and rename it to target your specific view.
form sites/all/contrib/views/theme/...

See this links really help you out:
http://www.wdtutorials.com/how-to-create-custom-template-view-drupal-tutorial-article/7#.VgQw5XU4bK4

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-templates/

Best of Luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the extensively answer, but this is not the case. I like to switch the template file in my preprocess function.